# Converting to Bigint in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a server function to convert data to bigint in MS SQL Server. The test data is `37040044053201300013148900`. The function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.convertToBigInt
(
    @value VARCHAR(64)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @convertedValue VARCHAR(20);
    
    SET @convertedValue = REPLACE(@value, ' ', '');

    RETURN @convertedValue;
END;
```

This leads me to a overflow error. Why? How can I improve the function?

Context: Later I am using this output in a function that needs a bigint as input-Variable.

Thank you so much!

Nina

Also tried to convert into numeric. Same Arithmetic Overflow. Test:

```
DECLARE @testValue VARCHAR(64) = '37040044053201300013148900';
DECLARE @convertedValue VARCHAR(20);

SET @convertedValue = dbo.convertToNumeric(@testValue);
SELECT @convertedValue AS ConvertedValue;
```

Comment: The function still returns a varchar(20), which is **NOT** a BigInt. Is that really what you intend? Anyway, most likely you have an input longer than 20 characters, even after removing the spaces. Also, the max value of BigInt stops in 19 characters... though I guess you could have 20 with a negative sign.

Comment: Max value of bigint is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.   You've far exceeded that

Comment: fyi   FLOAT would return  3.70400440532013E+25   You'd lose a little precision

Comment: What does the value represent? That number is staggeringly massive. I can't imagine a number that size where it needs to be a integer so you can do math with it.

Comment: You can do `decimal(38,0)` if you need integers larger than `bigint` for some reason

Comment: Why does this even need its own function?

Comment: Your in-house conversion function clearly doesn't handle large values. I think there's a concept you're not understanding and the goal of this whole exercise isn't clear to you or us.

Answer (score 2):

`37040044053201300013148900` is 26 digits. The best you can do with BIGINT is [19 digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (`9223372036854775807`), though thinking in terms of characters you could perhaps use 20 if you need a negative sign.

Anyway, the function doesn't even return a bigint. It returns a varchar(20), which is very much **NOT** the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`BIGINT` is simply too small to store your test value:

```
37040044053201300013148900 -- @TestValue
9223372036854775807        -- maximum value for bigints
```

`DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` is fine in this scenario, just go hard for the maximum available value for the type.

```
DECLARE @testValue VARCHAR(64) = '37040044053201300013148900'
--SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, @testValue)
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0), @testValue)
```

Have a look at *precision* and *scale* arguments for them here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16